# Static function that returns the dynamic type of class

Tags: swift

I'm following a design where each view controller is designed and configured on its own storyboard. For example `MyViewController` will be housed in `MyViewController.storyboard` and assigned the identifier `MyViewController`. This consistent naming allows me to write a convenient extension to `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func fromStoryboard(_ storyboard: UIStoryboard? = nil, identifier: String? = nil) -> UIViewController {
        let className  = NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        let storyboard = storyboard ?? UIStoryboard(name: className, bundle: nil)
        let identifier = identifier ?? className

        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}
```

And whenever I need the controller I can call it like this:

```
let vc = MyViewController.fromStoryboard() as! MyViewController
```

**My question is this:** how can I change the function so that I can remove the `as!` cast and still have `vc` of type `MyViewController`? In other words what I want to do is this:

```
let vcA = ViewControllerA.fromStoryboard()  // vcA is of type ViewControllerA
let vcB = ViewControllerB.fromStoryboard()  // vcB is of type ViewControllerB
```